# removing a container using the Jenkins Docker plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to use the Jenkins Docker plugin to achieve the equivalent of:

```
bat "docker rm -f SQLLinux${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
```

I presume this is possible, however the lack of documentation on this is hampering me, can someone point me in the correct direction as to how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: honest question out of curiosity here: why would you want to use a plugin for this? why not just execute the bat command you suggested?

Comment: Because when coding things, I like to be consistent where possible

Comment: ok, sure, since you're using other functions from this same plugin, it would be nice to use the plugin here as well. probably some of the other plugin functions provide more value than this one. thanks for entertaining my curiosity here; makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

This will be working on client side only.

Comment: i don't understand the answer. you're saying the plugin can't currently do this and the OP has to use something like the bat command he suggested?

Comment: fair. i upvoted. you might want to edit a bit to clarify.

Comment: @abhishek Sharma : if I would like to setup a time after stop before killing the container, how can I do so if built-in docker plugin is being used in pipeline?